# Check if username existed in SQLExpress

Tags: c#, sql

> Error shows : ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been
>   initialized and exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;

```
         bool exists = false;

         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [Users] where UserName = @UserName"))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", tbUserName.Text);
             exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
         }

         if (exists)
         {
             lblUserName.Text = "This username has been used by another user.";
         }
         else
         {
             SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
             SqlCommand cmd;

             cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users (UserID,FName, LName, PhoneNo, Address, Email, UserName, Password, Points, Role) VALUES (@UserID,@FName, @LName, @PhoneNo, @Address, @Email, @UserName, @Password, @Points, @Role)");

             try
             {
                 cmd.Connection = connection;
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", tbFName.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", tbLName.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNo", tbPhoneNo.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", tbAddress.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tbEmail.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", tbUserName.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", tbPassword.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Points", Points);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", Role);
                 connection.Open();
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }

             finally
             {
                 connection.Close();
                 //session
                 Session["UserName"] = tbUserName.Text;
                 Session["UserID"] = ("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'UserID'");
                 Session["Points"] = ("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Points = 'Points'");
                 //pop out then redirect 
                 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Success", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank you or signing up with us!');window.location='Home.aspx';</script>'");
            }         
      }
```

What should be the correct way to declare the connection first because I tried to put it before but I'm having problems with the cmd.

```
         SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

         SqlCommand cmd;
         bool exists = false;

         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [Users] where UserName = @UserName"))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", tbUserName.Text);
             exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
         }
```

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` returns first column of the first row, not a count of rows in the result set.

Comment: You should attempt the `INSERT` and catch the exception when the unique constraint on the username column is violated (you do *have* such a constraint, don't you?). Otherwise, you could have a race where two users are trying to register the same username - they both perform the `SELECT`, observe no rows, and then both attempt the `INSERT` - you may as well just code for the `INSERT` to fail and skip the earlier `SELECT`.

Comment: how do i catch the exception ?

Comment: `catch (SqlException ex) { if(ex.Number==2627) {//Unique constraint violation} else {throw;}}` would be a basic framework (can't get better formatting in comments)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the connection to the command in your last example

So within your using statement add:

```
 cmd.Connection = connection;
```

Additionally you don't need:

```
SqlCommand cmd;
```

as the command is created within the context of that `using` statement.

It's also considered good practice to wrap the `Connection` context within a using statement to ensure the actual connection get's disposed / closed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
{
    connection .Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [Users] where UserName = @UserName", connection );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", tbUserName.Text);
    bool exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
}
```

You didn't specified `connection` to `command`. Secondly you have to open connection.

Update: Complete Code

```
try
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    bool exists = false;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection .Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [Users] where UserName = @UserName", connection );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", tbUserName.Text);
        exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
    }

    if (exists)
    {
        lblUserName.Text = "This username has been used by another user.";
    }
    else
    {
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users (UserID,FName, LName, PhoneNo, Address, Email, UserName, Password, Points, Role) VALUES (@UserID,@FName, @LName, @PhoneNo, @Address, @Email, @UserName, @Password, @Points, @Role)", Connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", tbFName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", tbLName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNo", tbPhoneNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", tbAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tbEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", tbUserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", tbPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Points", Points);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", Role);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Do something
}
finally
{
    //session
    Session["UserName"] = tbUserName.Text;
    Session["UserID"] = ("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'UserID'");
    Session["Points"] = ("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Points = 'Points'");
    //pop out then redirect 
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Success", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank you or signing up with us!');window.location='Home.aspx';</script>'");
}
```

Comment: but the insert is not working now.. object reference is set to null

Answer (score 0):

SQL command should have a overload which takes an initiated connection

Answer (score 0):

Use `SqlCommand` constructor that takes connection as second argument. Next you have to open it before executing command and after that close it.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [Users] where UserName = @UserName", connection))
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", tbUserName.Text);

   connection.Open();

   exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;

   connection.Close();
}
```